# Power BI - Duplicate Rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI, I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID
234
435
3435
58
48504
7820
```

I want to convert it to a table that looks like this:

```
ID
234-101
234-102
435-101
435-102
3435-101
343-102
58-101
58-102
48504-101
48504-102
7820-101
7820-102
```

Is this even possible within Power BI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of two ways to do this, though there are probably others.

**NOTE** - I prefer the second method as it lets the "101" and "102" be data driven allowing them to be changed or added to in the future more easily.

**A) Through the Query Editor (requires hard-coding the "101"/"102" values)**

**Step 1:** Start with your data in the Query Editor
[image: Step A1 - Start]

**Step 2:** Add two additional columns for your suffixes. Click on the "Custom Column from Examples" button and then type in "234-101" in the first cell. After arrowing down to the next cell, it should auto-populate the rest. Do this again for "-102".
[image: Step A2 - Custom Columns]

**Step 3:** Unpivot the two new columns to get them into one. With the "ID" column selected, click on the dropdown for "Unpivot Columns" and click on "Unpivot Other Columns".
[image: Step A3 - Unpivot Columns]

**Step 4:** Remove extra columns. In the resulting data, you will have the original "ID" column, along with two new ones; "Attribute" and "Value". Since the "Value" column contains the desired values, select the "ID" and "Attribute" columns, right click one of their headers, and select "Remove Columns".
[image: Step A4 - Remove Columns]

**Step 5:** Rename the "Value" column to "ID" and you're finished.
[image: Step A5 - Rename Column]

Here is the resulting M code for all of those actions.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjI2UYrViVYyMTYF08YwhqkFRNzC1ACiwtzCyEApNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Merged", each Text.Combine({Text.From([ID], "en-US"), "-101"}), type text),
    #"Inserted Merged Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Merged Column", "Merged.1", each Text.Combine({Text.From([ID], "en-US"), "-102"}), type text),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column1", {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"ID", "Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", "ID"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

**B) Through DAX**

**Step 1:** Start with your data in the data view.
[image: Step B1 - Start]

**Step 2:** Click on "Enter Data" and add the data for the suffixes. (Skip this if these numbers are sourced somewhere else)
[image: Step B2 - Add Suffix Data]

**Step 3:** Click on "New Table" and enter the following formula.

```
NewData = CROSSJOIN(Data, Suffixes)
```

[image: Step B3 - New Table]

**Step 4:** Click on "New Column and enter the following formula.

```
NewID = CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(NewData[ID], "-"), NewData[Value])
```

[image: Step B4 - New Column]

If you want the new column to be named "ID", you'll need to rename the old "ID" column first, as you can't simply remove it like was done in the first method.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with using Power BI's query editor (Power Query) for this, you can do it with this query code:

```
let
Source = Table1,
#"Inserted Merged Column3" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "DelimitedListWithSuffixes", each Text.Combine({[ID], "-101,", [ID],"-102"}), type text),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column3", {{"DelimitedListWithSuffixes", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "DelimitedListWithSuffixes"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"DelimitedListWithSuffixes", type text}}),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"DelimitedListWithSuffixes"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"DelimitedListWithSuffixes", "ID"}})
in
#"Renamed Columns"
```

*(Table1 is your original ID column table.)*